# What is this plane approaching an airport in Asia? (Also, what is the airport?)

Tags: aircraft-identification, airport-identification

The airport is in Asia, that is all I know.

[image: Picture with partial cockpit view over mountains]

[image: Picture with partial cockpit view showing mountain airport]

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Welcome. If you still have the URLs in your browser history, please [add](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/55727/edit) the sources of the photos to the question, thanks.

Comment: This airport brings a whole new terror to [touch'n'go landings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch-and-go_landing)

Comment: @Richard Not a touch and go, but [missed approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LD5JhGMxow) below tree and roof top level through the village. Indeed a whole new terror.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The airport is [Lukla](https://www.google.com/maps/@27.6874828,86.7290351,754m/data=!3m1!1e3) - [Tenzing-Hillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing%E2%80%93Hillary_Airport) in Nepal.

The aircraft is a [Eurocopter AS350 Écureuil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS350_%C3%89cureuil) helicopter. I found a [picture of one that has the same panel layout](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8668153).

Comment: Other than "tiny airstrip in a mountainous region of Asia" I had absolutely no reason to think "Lukla", yet that's what came to mind. Guess I was right. Time to quit for the day!!

Comment: For the uninitiated: Lukla is often seen as the gateway to Sagarmatha/Mount Everest and features an unconventional runway which slopes noticeably down with the slope that it's on, in addition to having a variable slope.

Comment: @Jules: Oh, and it's also impossible to go around, because of the mountain in the way.